# Make HTML video background full height

Tags: css, html

Based on a [Pen in codepen.io](https://codepen.io/1wdtv/pen/meNOjG) I'm trying to achieve full screen video background with HTML5 and CSS3.

The problem here is that, if the viewport if the one of a mobile device (9:16) it'll leave a "blank" space under the video.

Tried the fix of adding "100vh" to the video's class but then the container for the text won't be centered and there'll be a big difference between containers.

HTML (Blade):

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('css')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/landing.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
@endsection

@section('content')
  <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#first"><i class="ion-ios-analytics-outline"></i> Matchmaking League</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Matches</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Teams</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Collaborate with us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <div class="header-content">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="cursive">CS:GO's Matchmaking League</h1>
        <h4>Catchy phrase here</h4>
        <hr>
        <a href="/login"><img src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_01.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" style="opacity:0.3" class="fillWidth fadeIn wow collapse in" data-wow-delay="0.5s" poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QMWYuCerQms/maxresdefault.jpg" id="video-background">
      <source src="https://r3---sn-0ox-cb5e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pl=20&ei=ZumfV8axFYaf-QX7oZmYCg&expire=1470119366&sver=3&mime=video%2Fmp4&signature=99A1ACC6A624430A54B1423D6027D44DD16BE2D7.A9AE7D0CAF6936F6C47D34BCBDBD9F1FC01A74C8&upn=_duYgHTjcoY&initcwndbps=453750&fexp=9416891%2C9419452%2C9422596%2C9428398%2C9431012%2C9432059%2C9433096%2C9433223%2C9433946%2C9435526%2C9435876%2C9436835%2C9437066%2C9437552%2C9438327%2C9438662%2C9438804%2C9438829%2C9439581%2C9439652%2C9439891%2C9439971%2C9440142%2C9440333%2C9440503%2C9440832%2C9440880%2C9441141%2C9441391%2C9441413%2C9441462%2C9441539%2C9442144%2C9442424%2C9443259&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&sparams=cnr%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&requiressl=yes&dur=515.947&id=o-AFu_KBjQb13V-QZfHEV4tJiiIWKICWdj4RrA4g-TJyv9&mm=31&cnr=14&mn=sn-0ox-cb5e&mt=1470097479&itag=22&key=yt6&ip=201.185.212.105&lmt=1466762275122028&ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
  </header>

  @endsection

  @section('js')

    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/landing.js"></script>
  @endsection
```

CSS:

```
/*

Landing Zero theme - A free landing page theme from BootstrapZero
http://www.bootstrapzero.com

*/

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script:700);

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Questrial','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #282828;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222;
}

hr {
    max-width: 80px;
    border-width: 3px;
    opacity: 0.09;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

hr.light {
    border-color: #fff;
}

a {
    color: #9c27b0;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #9c27c1;
    outline: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: 'Questrial','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wide-space {
    letter-spacing: 1.6px;
}

.icon-lg {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.bg-primary {
    background-color: #333;
}

.bg-dark {
    color: #eee;
    background-color: #222;
}

.cursive {
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    text-transform: none;
}

.text-faded {
    color: rgba(245,245,245,0.7);
}

.text-dark {
    color: #111;
}

.text-primary {
    color: #9c27b0;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

section {
    padding: 70px 0;
}

aside {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

footer {
    padding: 15px;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
    border-color: rgba(35,35,35,.05);
    font-family: 'Questrial','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #222;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.navbar-header > .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Questrial','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #9c27b0;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: padding .2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: padding .2s ease-in;
    transition: padding .2s ease-in;
}

.navbar-header > .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-header > .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #8b27b0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #181818;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle, .navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #eee;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
    color: #9c27b0;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #9c27b0 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover
{
    background-color: transparent;
}


@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        border-color: transparent;
        background-color: transparent;
        min-height: 60px;
    }

    .navbar-header > .navbar-brand {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        padding: 19px;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #f4f4f4;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        padding: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 1.1px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(60,60,60,0.7);
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fefefe;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
        border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
        background-color: #222;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #9c27b0;
        padding: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #8b27b0;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: #ddd;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(30,30,30,0.7);
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #9c27b0;
    }
}

header {
    position: relative;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}

header .header-content .inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

header .header-content .inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

#video-background {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

#video-background.collapsing {
  display:none;
}

footer {
    background-color:#2d2d2d;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .icon-lg {
        font-size: 80px;
    }

    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    header .header-content .inner h1 {
        font-size: 53px;
    }

    header .header-content .inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    section {
        min-height: 600px;
        padding: 100px 0;
    }

}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #eee;
    background-color: #36333d;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #36333d;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.form-control:focus {
    color: #222;
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-shadow: none;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

.margin-top-0 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.feature {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    max-width: 400px;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .feature {
        margin: 20px auto 0;
    }
}

.feature p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.call-to-action h2 {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.gallery-box {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 650px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.gallery-box .gallery-box-caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(44,44,44,.8);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.gallery-box .gallery-box-caption .gallery-box-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.gallery-box:hover .gallery-box-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-box:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.gallery-box img {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.no-gutter > [class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.

btn-default:hover,
    .btn-default:focus,
    .btn-default.focus,
    .btn-default:active,
    .btn-default.active,
    .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
        border-color: #ededed;
        color: #222;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .btn-default:active,
    .btn-default.active,
    .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
        background-image: none;
    }

    .btn-default.disabled,
    .btn-default[disabled],
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
    .btn-default.disabled:hover,
    .btn-default[disabled]:hover,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
    .btn-default.disabled:focus,
    .btn-default[disabled]:focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
    .btn-default.disabled.focus,
    .btn-default[disabled].focus,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
    .btn-default.disabled:active,
    .btn-default[disabled]:active,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
    .btn-default.disabled.active,
    .btn-default[disabled].active,
    fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
        border-color: #fff;
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .btn-default .badge {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #222;
    }

    .btn.btn-primary {
        background-color: transparent;
        border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
        border-color:#f0f0f0;
        -webkit-transition: all .35s;
        -moz-transition: all .35s;
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .btn.btn-primary:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .btn {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 290px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

.btn-xl {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

img::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}
```

I don't think the JS is relevant here but I'll add it if needed.

The site can be checked [here](http://mml.andresbuitrago.me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if you'll be 100% satisfied, but what I've tried (and was satisfied with it) was:

```
header, .header-content {
  height: 100%;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -5em auto 0;
}
```

it makes video 100% height + header text in the middle of screen

Comment: Worked perfectly! I was thinking I had to replace something in my css with that but then I realize that if I putted it on the bottom it would overwrite the things above. Would you explain why does this work and how? Thank you.

Comment: in CSS, last rule is applied, so it rewrites your class attributes. you can include it in your existing classes too, it would be better. header text alignment uses `position: relative`, so it doesn't break `margin: auto`, then it's pulled down by 50% height of the screen and then pulled back by 5em up to align in the middle (this can be customized, depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0):

### Full Sized Video

In the `header`, you have:

```
header {
    min-height: auto;
}
```

You should change this to:

```
header {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

### Centered Text

In your `landing.css` there is a media query for content over 768px. You want to:

1. Cut the CSS for `header .header-content` from the media query.
2. Paste it over the `header .header-content` that isn't in a media query.

Comment: The video height worked but the text isn't centered. It is to the left.